# Не работает правило валидации для вложенных массивов при обновлении в Laravel

Tags: laravel, валидация, rules

Приходит массив данных вида

```
  "id" => "2"
  "fio" => "Иванов Иван Иванович"
  "birthday" => "2022-10-21"
  "email" => "test@mail.ru"
  "phones" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => "7"
      "number" => "122"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => "10"
      "number" => "911"
    ]
  ]
```

Я хочу добавить проверку на уникальность.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'phones.*.number' => 'required|string|max:12|unique:'.Phone::class.',number,phones.*.id';
    ]
}
```

Проблема в том, что при обновлении данных возникает ошибка

```
Такое значение поля :"phones.0.number" уже существует.
Такое значение поля :"phones.1.number" уже существует.
```

Возможно, я что-то не правильно указал?

Comment: А какая ошибка?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar
Такое значение поля :"phones.0.number" уже существует.
 Такое значение поля :"phones.1.number" уже существует.

Comment: `phones.*.id`, нельзя так сделать вроде бы. Вы можете исключить значение через `$this->phones`, но я не знаю как быть с массивами.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar вроде бы можно, но извращался я по разному. dd($this->phones) показывает null.
Пробовал через замыкания сделать, однако в таком случае я не могу указать конкретный телефон в котором ошибка, а только для всего массива номеров.

Comment: @InDevX если просто добавить unique то при обновлении возникнет проблема.

Comment: @InDevX да я понял о чем вы говорили, при обновлении будет писать ошибку, что такое поле уже существует.

Comment: @InDevX Не совсем понял вопрос, использую rules внутри FormRequest.

Comment: @KordDEM самое простое - в rules проверяйте метод (`$this->method()`), если апдейт то он put или patch - в этом случае добавляйте в правило ещё id. Или второй вариант, создать 2 form request, хранить правила в модели, например, и изменять для апдейта 1 правило

Comment: @InDevX хотел, что-то менее костыльное)) Думал мб кастомное правило какое-то можно использовать, ведь задача часто встречающаяся. Реализовал через замыкания.

Comment: @KordDEM менее костыльное это отдельные store и update form request делать, всё остальное костыли, по большому счету

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому пригодится.
Сложные правила валидации приходится реализовывать через замыкания.

```
public function rules(){
        return [
            'phones.*.number' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'max:12',
                $this->ValidatePhone()
            ],
}

private function ValidatePhone(): \Closure
    {
        return function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (!empty(request()->input('phones'))){
                $search = collect(request()->input('phones'))->where('number', $value);
                if($search->count() > 1){ // если пробуем добавить несколько одинаковых номеров
                    $fail("Несколько одинаковых номеров");
                    return;
                }
                if(Phone::where('number', $value)->where('id', '!=', $search->first()['id'])->count())
                {
                    $fail("Номер уже существует");
                }
            }
        };
    }
```